# cassandra remove node from gossipinfo

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra version 3.6

Actully I want to remove a node "261.4.55.161" from cassandra So,

In previous I have 2 node of cassandra so I left a node with this command in the host "261.4.55.161".

```
[root@b59 conf]# "nodetool decommission"
```

now the node is not showing on "nodetool status cp" command only one node showing (this is what I want).

```
[root@b59 conf]# nodetool status cp;
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  12.111.41.22  43.8 GiB   256          100.0%            65f7597b-2l42-4bcb-a65a-53c25d4b7a13  rack1
```

But when I check the gossip with this command "nodetool gossipinfo"

This is still showing the node but "STATUS is LEFT", but I want to completely disable this node.

```
[root@b59 conf]# nodetool gossipinfo
/12.111.41.22
  generation:1524471400
  heartbeat:755047
  STATUS:20:NORMAL,-1025782309085114491
  LOAD:754953:4.7034856044E10
  SCHEMA:69:79958430-ad10-34dd-baf9-1ac87e9e7910
  DC:7:datacenter1
  RACK:9:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:5:3.6.0
  RPC_ADDRESS:4:12.111.41.22
  SEVERITY:755049:0.5
  NET_VERSION:2:10
  HOST_ID:3:65f7597b-2l42-4bcb-a65a-53c25d4b7a13
  RPC_READY:53:true
  TOKENS:19:<hidden>
/261.4.55.161
  generation:1524717007
  heartbeat:1500
  STATUS:1502:LEFT,-1003381131543138657,1524976696131
  LOAD:1481:6.4782307931E10
  SCHEMA:10:79958430-ad10-34dd-baf9-1ac87e9e7910
  DC:6:datacenter1
  RACK:8:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:4:3.6
  RPC_ADDRESS:3:261.4.55.161
  SEVERITY:1499:0.0
  NET_VERSION:1:10
  HOST_ID:2:a98d0b43-2b66-4b95-b8a6-e81197d9eb9d
  RPC_READY:42:true
  TOKENS:13:<hidden>
```

I don't want to show this node in gossipinfo also.

my question is how do I remove this node 261.4.55.161 from gossipinfo?

Answer (score 2):

It should go away after awhile (few days i think it is) it remains in that state in gossip info as a precaution incase a node was offline and missed the decommission. It shouldn't be hurting anything in LEFT state, you can just ignore it. In left state its no longer part of the cluster.

There is a `nodetool assassinate` (on newer versions, older have to call JMX yourself) to forcibly remove it from gossip, but really theres no need to do that. Best to just ignore it.